# How to add multiple ids in mapbox on?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've 3 mapbox layers of different ids

```
map.addLayer({
             'id': '1',
             ...
            });

map.addLayer({
             'id': '2',
             ...
            });

map.addLayer({
             'id': '3',
             ...
            });
```

and I have to add all of these id's on mapbox on `mouseenter` and also `mouseleave`like this
map.on('mouseenter','1', function(e){

```
    });
```

but I've to make saperate functions on those 3 different ids,
I want to add all ids in this `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` at once, so that i dont have to make saperate for 3 different ids.

How can i do this guys?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. There is no shortcut. You can of course define the function once and pass it three times:

```js
const enterHandler = e => { ... }
map.on('mouseenter', '1', enterHandler);
map.on('mouseenter', '2', enterHandler);
map.on('mouseenter', '3', enterHandler);
```

You may want to look at [map-gl-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-gl-utils) which has some convenience methods such as `hoverPointer` which may help you.

Comment: there is no shortcut, although thanks anyway :)